# Relationships Laravel between multiple models

Tags: laravel, eloquent-relationship

I have multiple tables :

```
Season
- id
- number

Serie
- id 
- name

Actor
- id 
- name

CastingSerie
- id
- serie_id
- actor_id
- personnage

CastingSeason
- id
- casting_serie_id
- season_id
```

All the relationships that I have so far :

```
Season Model

 public function serie()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Serie::class);
    }

 public function personnages() 
    {
        return $this->hasMany(CastingSeason::class, 'season_id');
    }

 public function actors() {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(Actor::class, CastingSeason::class, 'season_id', 'serie_id', 'id', 'id');
    }

--------

Serie model

  public function seasons() 
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Season::class);
    }

  public function personnages() 
    {
        return $this->hasMany(CastingSerie::class);
    }

  public function actors() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Actor::class, CastingSerie::class, 'serie_id', 'actor_id');
    }

------

Actor model

 public function series() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Serie::class, 'casting_serie', 'actor_id', 'serie_id');
    }

 public function personnages() {
        return $this->hasMany(CastingSerie::class);
    }
```

I want to retrieve for one Actor, every personnages that he plays from all the seasons of a serie like. I want a link to every series and seasons if possible. Like $serie->name ($season->number). I already have all the series for one actor but I would like to get all the seasons instead

Comment: It is not clear to what you really want. I may help if you specify or show us what you did and what output you get; and what you want to do and what you want to accomplish.

Comment: Thanks so much for your response !
At this point, I made this in the view :

 foreach($acteur->personnages as $personnage) 
      foreach($personnage->serie->seasons as $season)
           <td>{{$personnage->serie->year}}</td>
           <td>{{$personnage->serie->name}} (Saison {{$season->number}})</td>
           <td>{{$personnage->personnage}}</td>
     endforeach
endforeach

It gaves me all the series of an actor with the season attach by displaying all the seasons of a serie automatically. But 1 actor can be just in 2 seasons of a serie who have 5 seasons

Comment: So I need to display the CastingSeason and not the CastingSerie. When I add an CastingSerie in my db, for each season of the serie, i add a Casting Season.
There is a column in my CastingSeason which is boolean to know if the CastingSeason is true or not

Comment: I tried this also but it showing multiple loops for the same records :

In my ActorController :  $acteur->load('series.serie.seasons.personnages');

In my view : 
foreach($acteur->series as $serie)
    foreach($serie->serie->seasons as $season)
      foreach($season->personnages as $personnage)
        {{$personnage->season_id}}
     endforeach
   endforeach
endforeach

Comment: My end point is to have :

Actor->name

For all the season of the actor :
Serie->name (season->number)

Comment: Maybe I should refractor the casting_serie table with the season_id? Which way would be the more optimize?